# Do these Garuda Purana verses say that Karma is supreme and acts on all?

Tags: karma, garuda-purana

I came across interesting verses in [Garuda purana](https://archive.org/details/GarudaPuranaEnglishMotilal3VolumesIn1/page/n350) verses (1.113.14-16)

> 14. Bhima, Arjuna and others were born as princes, they were pleasing and delightful like the moon; they were valorous, truthful, brilliant
>       like the sun and **were kindly protected by Lord Krishna. Even they were
>       subjected to abject misery by the influence of evil planets; they
>       had to beg for alms.; if fate is adverse who is capable of what ?** The
>       current of previous actions tosses every one about.
> 15. Obeisance to Karma which forces **Brahma to work like a potter** in the bowls of cosmos by which **Visnu was cast into distress of ten
>       incarnations;** by which **Rudra was compelled to beg for alms** with a
>       skull in his hand and at the behest of which the **sun goes round and
>       round in the sky.**
> 16. The donor was King Bali, the receiver Lord Visnu himself, the gift consisted of whole Earth and that too in the presence of learned
>       brahmins. **What did he get in return ? Only bondage. O Fate ! obeisance
>       to Thee—who workest as it pleasest thee.**

What are the stories of each god that caused them to be bound in that manner?

But, we also hear statements from Gita that "I am not bound by any karma" etc..

Does the Garuda purana verses prove supremacy of karma over all the gods as well?

Comment: You know well the difference between the  God and the gods!

Comment: These verses look like a eulogy of karma. They are not to be taken as literally applying to Brahma, Vishnu, Shiva.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to understand that the supreme lord is the supreme indeed even time is subordinate to him.

Lord vishnu's devotees are excused of their Karma to certain extent. a true devotee is not liable to law of karma.
I will prove That lord Vishnu/Krishna is supremacy,

Garuda Purana 3.1.41

na cāsti viṣṇoḥ sadṛśaṃ ca daivataṃ na cāsti vāyoḥ sadṛśo guruśca
na cāsti tīrthaṃ sadṛśaṃ viṣṇupadyāḥ na viṣṇubhaktena samosti bhaktaḥ

This verse says that explains that in all ways Vishnu/ krishna is supreme.

Srimad Bhagavatam, vishnu purana and many other scriptures accept this.
Vishnu Bhagavan willingly had to come down to earth.
Bali Maharaja got a place in lower heavenly planet system Srimad Bhagavatam 5.24
Vishnu Bhagavan wanted to take avatar.
People who are liable to karma get their results because of it.
So the karma is given to us by god.He only gives the specific results
Jai Jaganath.
Radhekrishna.
Ramakrishna Ki Jai
Granth Raja Bhagvatam Ki jai.

Answer (score 1):

From your question

1. Pandavas were never in distress they know their true self. why because they devathas in manusya deha. Begging in Ekachakra nagara is hide their identity of shatrya so that duryodhana will not know, they did it on instruction of Sage and Lord Veda vyasa, that too for finishing Bhakasura at the right time after that they never begged.
2. Lord Vishnu was never cast into the world by any entity. it was his own willingness and to meet the needs of his devotees, who wants to do moksha sadha just by thinking the deeds of 10 avataras.
3. Rudra is Jiva just like anyother devathas as stated in point one all devathas know their true selfs, so they need not worry about karma or not bound by karma as you think
4. Bali is going next indra so for him karma affected

Answer (score 0):

Like most controversial, contradictory, and problematic things in Hindu holy books, this is because of the book repeating things it does not truly endorse.

This one is kind of confusing in that it is Yājñavalkya talking about what Sūta has said.

The fact it is a quotation and that it is not truly endorsed can be seen earlier.

> Maheśvara said:
>
> 1. O Hari, the destroyer of Keśin, how was virtue expounded by Yājñavalkya formerly. Please explain to me as the facts are, O Mādhava
>
> Hari said:
>
> 2. After making obeisance to Yājñavalkya who was staying in Mithilā, the sages asked him about the various duties of different castes. With due meditation on Viṣṇu the sage of controlled senses expounded the same to them
>
> Yājñavalkya said:
>
> 3-6. **The virtue expounded hereafter is current in that country where the black deer roam about freely...**

A lot of Hindu scriptures quote people saying stuff that doesn't make sense or contradicts Hinduism. While Yājñavalkya is better than a random person off the street, there is no reason to think that everything he says is true or well thought out. Also, the context is just to explain dharma at that specific time and place. Thus, it does not really matter, even to him, if he gets other stuff wrong or exaggerates.